# Celsius to Fahrenheit loop in list

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to create a list of Celsius to Fahrenheit temperature conversions from celsius range 0-100 in increments of 0.5. This is what I have so far but I can't seem to get the loop to run correctly because it starts with celsius:0 fahrenheit:0; I need it to start with celsius:0 fahrenheit:32 (the correct conversion).

```
count = 0
celsius = 0
while (celsius <= 100):
   print ('Celsius:', celsius, 'Fahrenheit:', count)
   celsius = celsius + 0.5
   count = (((celsius)*9/5)+32)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is more something like this:

```
celsius = 0
while celsius <= 100:
    fahrenheit = celsius * 9.0/5.0 + 32
    print ('Celsius:', celsius, 'Fahrenheit:', fahrenheit)
    celsius += 0.5
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you write a function?

```
def toFarenheit(celsius):
    return (9.0/5.0) * celsius + 32

def toCelsius(farenheit):
    return (farenheit - 32) * (5.0 / 9.0)
# I don't actually use this method, but it's still good to have
```

Then, you can do:

```
for y in range(0,200):
    x = y / 2.0
    print("Celsius: ", x, ", Farenheit: ", toFarenheit(x))
```